# A couple of chars are not printing

Tags: c, visual-studio, char, scanf

I am learning C programming! I am trying to write a program
but some things dont work as they should!
Here is the code and i will explain below!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS


int main(void)
{
    int afm, date, month, year,code;
    char name_in, surn_in, slash, category;
    float income, tax;
    do {
        printf("Give afm : "); /*Give a 10 digit number*/
        scanf("%d", &afm);
        if (afm < 1000000000 || afm > 9999999999) {
            printf("Incorrect!\n");
        }
    } while (afm < 1000000000 || afm > 9999999999);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Give your name's first letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &name_in);
        getchar();
        printf("Give surname's first letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &surn_in);
        getchar();

    do
        {
        printf("Date of birth(must be at least 18) : ");
        scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &date, &slash, &mhnas, &slash, &etos); /*just write 20/10/1987 */
        if (month < 1 || month>12) {
            printf("Incorrect month. \n");
        }
        if (year > 1997) {
            printf("Year incorrect \n");
        if (2015 - year == 18 && month==12 ) {
            printf("Incorrect date of birth.\n");

            }
        }
    } while ((month < 1 || month>12) || (year > 1997) || (2015 - year == 18 && mhnas == 12));
    printf("Add your income ");
    scanf("%f", &income);

    code = afm % 10; /*need to find the afm's last digit*/

    if (code == 1 || code == 2 || code == 3) {
        category = "Misthwtos";
        if (income <= 10000) {
            tax = 0;
        }
        if (income > 10000 && income <= 30000) {
            tax = (eisodhma - 10000) * 20 / 100;
        }
        if (income > 30000)
            tax = (20000 * 20 / 100) + ((eisodhma - 30000) * 30 / 100);
    }

    if (code != 1 || code != 2 || code != 3) {
        tax = income * 30 / 100;
    }

    printf("Info: \n");
    printf("%d %c.%c. &d/%d/%d",afm, name_in, surn_in, date, month, year);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, the problem is that, when the program prints what I ask at the end of the code, it print everything except the characters `name_in` and `surn_in`. I can't find a solution, can you help me?

PS. I am coding in Visual Studio

Comment: Why are these `getchar();`s in between `scanf`s? They are the problem.

Comment: and `fflush(stdin);` is UB.

Comment: i used to have fflush(stdin) between them but something wrong was happening so i randomly put those and it worked :p

Comment: Programming by experimenting is a **bad** idea in most cases. You should understand what your code does.

Comment: Did you debug the code, tracing it step by step and inspecting all relevant variables while doing so?

Comment: `(20000 * 20 / 100) + ((eisodhma - 30000) * 30 / 100);` the literals are all integer, so integer division ins applied. This surely is not what you want. Change it be `(20000. * 20. / 100.) + ((eisodhma - 30000.) * 30. / 100.);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`afm > 9999999999` is always false for `int afm`.  On your platform, `int` and `long` are 32 bits long, therefore limited to values less than `2147483647`.

You should use type `long long` for these variables.

Parse them with `scanf` format `%lld`

`fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour.  You probably want to get rid on any type ahead from the user: this cannot be done portably in C, and is of dubious value anyway.

`tax = (eisodhma - 10000) * 20 / 100;` refers to an undefined variable.  Did you mean `tax = (income - 10000) * 20 / 100;`?

`scanf("%c", &name_in);` does not read the next character, it reads the `'\n'` that is bufferized in the standard input.  To skip spaces, chux suggests this simple fix:

```
scanf(" %c", &name_in);
```

Most importantly:

```
if (code != 1 || code != 2 || code != 3)
```

is always true.  You really mean this:

```
if (code != 1 && code != 2 && code != 3)
```

Comment: i understand the mistake but why did it still worked?

Comment: It might *work* because that's what your platform implementation does.  The Standard says it invokes undefined behaviour, so anything goes.  Just be warned that it might crash on a different OS.

Comment: yes, the it is income :p the variables are supposed to be in greek written with english letters :p

Comment: What a curious requirement.  I work in France but I always require all identifiers to be in English for consistency and ease of communication among international readers.  Greek with latin letters is still greek to me;-)

Comment: Instead of `while (scanf("%c", name_in) == 1 && isspace((unsigned char)name_in)) continue;`, suggest `scanf(" %c", name_in);`  (add space)

Answer (score 2):

You missed a required `getchar()` before you scan for the `name_in`. Otherwise, it reads the last newline. The effects propagates for `surn_in`, too.

FWIW, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. Get rid of that.